# Leniency for Dangerous Surgery

Tags: sources-mekorot, medicine

The Chochmas Adam apparently writes that a patient is allowed to undergo a risky medical operation which may effectively end the patient's life during surgery for the chance that he will live longer. Where is this Chochmas Adam?

Note: I found an [article](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/high-risk-medical-procedures-part-one-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter) quoting "Binat Adam (73,93)" but I can't find that in the [Binas Adam](https://www.sefaria.org/Binat_Adam?lang=bi) anywhere.

Comment: Sefaria is often missing chunks of works. Did you try looking at an actual book/PDF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the back of most Chochmas Adam.
[image: Here]